# Context in tMap

Tags: talend

I've encountered an issue with using context variables in tMap expression builder. When I push a test button it gives me an error. Please find the screen attached.

[image]

I would be really appreciated for any suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the "?" at the end

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar the same error
but after "?" there is a condition

Comment: I change the screen - @IbrahimMezouar

Comment: @bdbd what you are trying to do in your filter ?  It's not clear the purpose of your condition .  You cannot convert from Object & Serializable & Comparable<?> to boolean

Comment: I create context date_app the value is for exemple 20200805. I have a list of file contain and date.
So I want if the date_app is not null then I want the file name and date equals to context date_app else date_app null I want file name and date equal to current date
PS: the date in file is like that "yyyyMMdd" I put in tmap with type sting

Answer (score 0):

a reference to a context variable is case sensitive. Use `context`, not `Context` and respect the case of the variable name.